# call class python using Geany in Ubuntu

Tags: python

I used Geany for editor python in ubuntu, and I created a file containing the class.

this my file. Time1.py

```
class Time:

    def __int__(self):
        self.hour = 0
        self.minute = 0
        self.second = 0

    def printMilitary(self):
        print "%.2d:%.2d:%.2d" % \
          (self.hour, self.minute, self.second),

    def printStandard(self):

        standardtime = ""
        if self.hour == 0 or self.hour == 12:
            standardTime += "12:"
        else:
            standardTime += "%d:" % ( self.hour % 12 )
        standardTime += "%.2d:%.2d" % ( self.minute, self.second )

        if self.hour < 12:
            standardTime += " AM"
        else:
            standardTime += " PM"
        print standardTime,
```

so I called it in mytime.py

```
from Time1 import Time

time1 = Time()

print "The attributes of time1 are: "
print "time1.hour:", time1.hour
print "time1.minute:", time1.minute
print "time1.second:", time1.second
```

after that I tried to run this script. but I got error. This the error

> The attributes of time1 are: 
>   time1.hour:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "untitled.py", line 31, in 
>       print "time1.hour:", time1.hour
>   AttributeError: Time instance has no attribute 'hour'

can you help me

Comment: Is this just a test, or are you not aware of the `datetime` module? Just wanted to make sure? `datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")`,  `datetime.now().strftime("%I:%M:%S %p")`

Comment: yes...I just learn..so I experiment make that

Comment: @jdi so what's wrong with my code ?

Comment: Amber already told you. You mis-spelled `__init__`. You should just accept her answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__int__` needs to be `__init__`.

Comment: Ok you win. You have 20/20 vision.

Comment: @Amber in my class ?? already... `def __int__(self):
        self.hour = 0
        self.minute = 0
        self.second = 0
`

Comment: @J.C you're missing an `i` in `init`.